# React Native - Perform loop for printAsync table

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I'm trying to do a `printAsync`, and this is the part where i'm blocked:

```
Print.printAsync({
        html: `
<html>
    <table class="formPayment">
        <tr>
            <td><strong>Código - Descrição</strong></td>
            <td class="tdRight"><strong>Qtde</strong></td>
            <td><strong>UN</strong></td>
            <td class="tRight"><strong>Vl Unit.</strong></td>
            <td class="tRight"><strong>Vl Total</strong></td>
        </tr>

        //where I intend to place the loop return
        // <tr>
        //    <td>${items[i].produtoId}</td><td>${items[i].quantidadeDeEmbalagem}</td><td>${items[i].unidade}</td><td class="tRight">${items[i].valorEmbalagem}</td><td class="tRight">${items[i].valor}</td>
        // </tr>

    </table>
</html>
```

but because it is a `printAsync()` from react-native `<script>` will not work. Then the loop should be previously and in string form with the html structure mentioned above.

```
for(let i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
    this.setState({itemsTabelaCodigo: `<td>${items[i].produtoId}</td><td>${items[i].quantidadeDeEmbalagem}</td><td>${items[i].unidade}</td><td>${items[i].valorEmbalagem}</td><td>${items[i].valor}</td>`})
}
```

Can anybody help me?
Thanks

Note: I'm using `"expo": "~ 36.0.0"`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to correct,

```
for(let i = 0; i < items.length; i++){

        **await** this.setState({itemsTabelaCodigo: `${this.state.itemsTabelaCodigo}<tr><td>${items[i].produtoId}-${items[i].descricaoProdutoEcommerce}</td><td>${items[i].quantidadeDeEmbalagem}</td><td>${items[i].unidade}</td><td class="tRight">${items[i].valorEmbalagem}</td><td class="tRight">${items[i].valor}</td></tr>`})
      }
const itemsTabela = this.state.itemsTabelaCodigo.toString()
```

and in the table part of the html

```
<table class="formPayment">
        <tr>
            <td><strong>Código - Descrição</strong></td>
            <td class="tdRight"><strong>Qtde</strong></td>
            <td><strong>UN</strong></td>
            <td class="tRight"><strong>Vl Unit.</strong></td>
            <td class="tRight"><strong>Vl Total</strong></td>
        </tr>

        ${itemsTabela}

    </table>
```